# PHP based source control (webSVN)

Tags: php, version-control, open-source

I have a shared linux hosting server which supports php so I was looking for a web based source control written in PHP.

I tried php version of webSVN but its giving following error after copying `distconfig.php` to `config.php` (I understood the warning previously mentioned by me.):

```
Error running this command: svn  --config-dir /tmp --version

sh: svn: command not found
```

What I think is the problem with permissions on my shared hosting server. Possibly my hosting server is not allowing to run a linux command. However, there must be a solution right?

If webSVN cannot run on shared server, any alternatives I can use for this purpose?
I already tried ASVCS, it works well, but provide very few functionalities. We need to use a ftp manager separately for doing any changes to any files. Not even upload or download functions are given in it.

Comment: this warning is already discussed many times

Comment: The warning means the user has already received something when a header is being sent. usually countered by `ob_start()` at the top of the page.

Comment: Yeah I know about the warning, the question is why its showing the warning, as I didn't touched the code of webSVN, it should be stable right.

Comment: @dragon112 thats a great performance degradation

Comment: @ArunKillu I know it is, I'm just giving a quick and dirty solution to a problem. The best way would obviously be to check where the headers are being sent and correct it.

Comment: yes thats also a solution but i mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error running command from the command include prints to your screen. Therefor the warning is given that the headers are already sent..

You probably installed the application incorrectly.

The error `svn: command not found` indicates you haven't installed SVN on your server (yet).

Comment: Ok I will try to install it again. But I followed the instructions carefully.

Comment: ```svn: command not found```

you haven't installed SVN on your server

Answer (score 0):

The "Cannot modify headers" warning is because you have already sent data to the response before trying to set header information.  The underlying cause is the "command not found".  I suspect you have a path problem or svn isn't installed.

SVN must be installed on the system path.  You should call your hosting provider's tech support, they may need to do the install for you or it may not be possible on that host.

Comment: Are you talking about SVN not installed in my linux server?? I copied all the php files to a directory. That's all I need to do right??? I don't have any control over my server, can't install linux scripts on it.

Comment: The error is saying that the file is either not there or the path is incorrect.  If this is shared hosting, it may not be there.